# Printing List data in table

Tags: html, jsp

I am beginner in jsp. I have called method getUserList() in a .jsp file which returns  user's list.
I want to print this result in html table.How I could do that...Thanks in advance.

```
<%List<User> ulist=ServiceFactory.getUserService().getUSerList();
 System.out.println(ulist);%>

<table>
<%for(User list:ulist){ %>
<tr>
<td><% list.getName();%></td>
</tr>
<%} %>
```

Comment: `<% list.getName();%>` --> `<%= list.getName() %>`

Comment: This worked.Thank you